# Using YouTube API on Android App

Tags: android, youtube, android-youtube-api

Okay, so I have a bit of a predicament. I built an app that basically just is a container for a website that has a curated collection of YouTube videos. It is built in Java for Android. The problem is that when I click play on any of the videos it uses a crappy built in player for WebView and doesn't even have an expand button. It also doesn't have like/dislike buttons which I would very much like to have. My question is, can I use the YouTube API to load the videos with its player without changing the website, as it is supposed to be used on desktop without any API as well.

Thanks in advance...

Comment: you can actually open the youtube app with the video if you have a valid youtube Url

Comment: I want to try and keep them in the app when watching if possible, though I use the YouTube embed code so I don't think it would work.

Comment: You can't embed another application in your application in android, you can open another application's activity from a button click in your app, but the other app should already be installed on the User's device

Comment: That's why I want to use the YouTube API

Comment: https://developers.google.com/youtube/android/player/

Comment: Would I be able to do what I wanted with that though? That's what I had in mind from the beginning but I wasn't sure if I could use it for what I wanted.

Comment: yes the api provides, UI widgets, like how android provides ImageView or videoView to play videos

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[This should rightly match your requirements](https://developers.google.com/youtube/android/player/#How_It_Works), this api provides different UI widgets, if you use Proguard then the apk size increase will be minimal from the library, you can find all the info on that website. Plus there is [the demo video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?list=PLhBgTdAWkxeDcgr7lljcTt1bKaHY48Toi&v=fhWaJi1Hsfo) you can get the [usage sample code here](https://github.com/youtube/api-samples).

Happy coding !

Comment: I'm not sure that that will work since what it is displaying is just a website. How would I incorporate it?

Comment: @Nickthegoatboy i provided links for the demo video and usage samples too