# Need a guide to authorizing an Android app with the YouTube api

Tags: android, youtube, oauth-2.0, youtube-api

So I've been trying for almost two hours now to authenticate with YouTube from an Android app and it just isn't working. It seems like the preferred method keeps changing, and the parts that I can find that are still relevant are missing big pieces. Could someone who's done this explain what I need to do. All I want to do is fetch a user's playlists from YouTube. I'm sorry I can't provide more to go off of, but I don't even know where to start at this point. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to check [Creating OAuth 2.0 credentials](https://developers.google.com/youtube/android/player/register#Create_OAuth2_Tokens) wherein it mentioned about the use of Service Account to be used in an application that calls APIs on behalf of an application that does not access user information.

And for installed applications, you can create OAuth 2.0 credentials for Android with these guidelines:

> You need to specify your Android app's package name and SHA1 fingerprint.
>
> 1. In the Package name field, enter your Android app's package name.
> 2. In a terminal, run the Keytool utility to get the SHA1 fingerprint for your digitally signed `.apk` file's public certificate.

```
keytool -exportcert -alias androiddebugkey -keystore path-to-debug-or-production-keystore -list -v
```

> 3. Paste the SHA1 fingerprint into the form where requested.
> 4. Click Create.

This [tutorial](http://createdineden.com/blog/post/android-tutorial-how-to-integrate-youtube-videos-into-your-app/) and a [related SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35801585/using-youtube-api-on-android-app) might also help.